# Open-source US- state status display

Tags: css, open-source

I was wondering if anyone knew of an Open-source project for displaying numbers for the US states.

Specifically, you always see these graphics with California in dark grey, Montana in green, etc. Based on some sort of criteria.

I'm thinking of building one for a site I maintain, but I was hoping I might not have to reinvent the wheel.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/World_map_of_Energy_consumption_1979-1981.svg

Something like the above, but for the US, and you can define your own criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution to this issue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_US_Map.svg

Simple SVG(xml document). Simply traverse and change the fill/stroke/whatever values as needed. You may need to convert to raster when done so that IE(groan) works, but it's really a very simple and easy solution.

Update: here's a sample javascript+jquery code block that will update the states via a percentage parameter. Transitions from white to blue.

```
for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        var state = states[i];
        var stateDom = $("#"+state.id);
        var domArray = [];
        //hack to support multiple path state of Michigan
        if(stateDom.is("path"))
            domArray.push(stateDom);
        else {
            var children = $("#"+state.id + " path");
            for(var k = 0; k < children.length; k++){
                domArray.push($(children[k]));
            }
        }
        for(var l = 0; l < domArray.length; l++) {
            var stateObj = domArray[l];
            //Onlick event for each state
//              var closed = function (percentage) {
//                  return function (){
//                      alert("P"+percentage);
//                  }
//              }(state.percentage);
//              stateObj.click(closed);
                var svgStyle = stateObj.attr("style");
                var stylesArray = svgStyle.split(";");
                svgStyle = "";
                for(var j = 0; j < stylesArray.length; j++) {
                    var styleObj = stylesArray[j].split(":");
                    if(styleObj[0] == "fill") {
                        var mask = 256 - Math.round((state.percentage)/100 * 256);
                        styleObj[1] = "rgb("+mask+","+mask+",256)";
                    }
                    svgStyle += styleObj[0]+":"+styleObj[1] +";";
                }
                stateObj.attr("style",svgStyle);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [maps in the Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#maps). You can select countries and colors programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the best I could find specifically in open source.

I would take a plugin like this just change it to do "highlighting" based on your dynamic data:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight
- Demo of plugin: http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

Currently it highlights on mouseover, but highlighting using data given should be very straightforward.

The fact it comes with a map of the US and highlighting ready to go set is just gravy.